# RelativeLayout crashes, LinearLayout works fine! WHY?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator

I'm new to Android programming (although I'm an expert in C and intermediate in Java).

I don't understand why my app crashes when I try to setContentView() with the default RelativeLayout that Eclipse automatically generates when I create a new project.

It crashes both in Emulater and on my phone.

But if I change the layout to a LinearLayout it works perfectly fine.

Can anybody give me a clear explanation to why this hapens?

Thanks

Comment: Without the code, we can't do much. Please post the code! For bonus points, post the stack trace.

Comment: show your logcat error and your relative.xml file , for better understanding

Comment: I did not post code because I thought this is something well known. Apparently it only hapens to me :) I'll post.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly let me explain you about layouts and follow the given example:

Now let’s turn our attention to those helpful layout controls that organize other controls. The most commonly used layout classes are:

**FrameLayout** – designed to display a stack of child View controls. Multiple view controls can be added to this layout. This can be used to show multiple controls within the same screen space.

**LinearLayout** – designed to display child View controls in a single row or column. This is a very handy layout method for creating forms.

**RelativeLayout** – designed to display child View controls in relation to each other. For instance, you can set a control to be positioned “above” or “below” or “to the left of” or “to the right of” another control, referred to by its unique identifier. You can also align child View controls relative to the parent edges.

**TableLayout** – designed to organize child View controls into rows and columns. Individual View controls are added within each row of the table using a TableRow layout View (which is basically a horizontally oriented LinearLayout) for each row of the table.

try the following code for relative layout:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="5dp">
        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textMsg"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="14dp" />
    </LinearLayout>


<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn2"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:text="Contacts"
    android:textColor="#342D7E" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn1"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:text="Send"
    android:textColor="#342D7E" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edittext1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/btn2"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Type a Message"
    android:maxLines="5" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>
</RelativeLayout>
```

let me know if it crashes again

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem.

How I fixed it:
After changing the layout in main.xml I had the layout declared in the mainActivity.java file still as a LinearLayout.

Go into your mainActivity.java file and change it to relatively out.

Check yours it might solve it